# Permission denied for subdirectory in Apache

Tags: linux, apache, permissions, webserver

I have apache running on port 80. I have also created an additional conf file in conf.d that would open up a second port 8010 with a different directory but I am unable to get to subdirectories now of the document root of 8010

```
Listen 8010
<VirtualHost ip:8010>
DocumentRoot /var/www/boom
ServerName localhost
ErrorLog logs/dm-error_log
CustomLog logs/dm-access_log common

<Directory /var/www/boom>
AuthName "Protected Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/secure/passwords
Require valid-user
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I try to go to ip:8010/banq I get the following error 
Forbidden You don't have permission to access /banq/ on this server.

I tried chmod 777 on banq with no luck

I had this all working great for few years and then lost all backups, had to recreate from scratch. I was able to move conf file from 1 server to another without setting any any chown and minor chmod commands. Is it possible to open all subdirectories of /var/www/boom to anyone who authenticates properly?

Answer (score 1):

Two things I have encountered that could cause a similar error would be:

1. Apache can't access the document root of where the banq/ directory is found. Have you checked permissions on /var/www/boom? Setting the group to apache or nobody, or making the directory world readable would be a good test.
2. If there is no directory index in banq/ Apache may prevent you from viewing a directory listing. Try adding either an index.html page to the directory for testing, or add "Options +Indexes" to the config file.